# Best practice to reuse RecyclerView layout in other places

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `Fragment` which contains a `RecyclerView` to display a list of items in a feed. However, an individual item might be opened in another `Fragment` with the same layout it has in the `RecyclerView`.

What would be the best practice for this scenario? Could/should I create a separate `Fragment` for the item and use it somehow in the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you create `RecyclerView` in the first fragment, you also create **layout** for the item you want to display. In the other, fragment you can just include the **layout** of the item. I don't think it can get more simple than that.

My practice is, i try to identify items that repeat itself and i try to create general layouts, for example, layout with **title** and **subtitle** and the use this layout in `RecyclerView` or just include it. Good thing here is that `RecyclerView` allows you to have different layouts and instead of drawing views or including it (if there are more view in fragment that i have created), i just add it to one `RecyclerView`.

Comment: In my case, such items are not static and I fill them in runtime (perhaps I should've included this info in the question). It feels a bit bundersome to repeat the procedures to correctly layout it in both the `RecyclerView`'s `ViewHolder` and in the `onCreateView` of the other fragment, you know? I would rather centralize this somehow...

Comment: I agree! how did you eventually solve this?

Comment: It's been 5 years :) @AlexBusuioc If you Use Kotlin, one option would be to create extension function, and use it both in the adapter and fragment.